# appending element to the page hides input field

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays, object

I am learning JavaScript and and I have got the working code for my program. Only problem I ma facing is that when findBooking method is called and result table displayed on the page it hides the search field. An idea how to fix it?

```js
var find = document.getElementById('find');
var inputBox = document.getElementById('inputBox');


function CustomerBooking ( custId, custName, film, showDate ) {
  
  this.custId = custId;
  this.custName = custName;
  this.film = film;
  this.showDate = showDate;
}

CustomerBooking.prototype.getCustId = function (){
  return this.custId;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setCustId = function (custId) {
  this.custId = custId;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getCustName = function (){
  return this.custName;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setCustName = function (custName) {
  this.custName = custName;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getFilm = function (){
  return this.film;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setFilm = function (film) {
  this.film = film;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getShowDate = function (){
  return this.showDate;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setShowDate = function (showDate) {
  this.showDate = showDate;
};

function Cinema () {
  this.bookings = [];
}

Cinema.prototype.addBooking = function(custId, custName, film, showDate){
  this.bookings[custId] = new CustomerBooking(custId, custName, film, showDate);
};

Cinema.prototype.findBooking = function () {
  var findID = parseInt(inputBox.value);
    var bookingSummary = "<table  border='1'>";
    for ( var booking in this.bookings ) {
         if ( findID === this.bookings[booking].custId ) {
             bookingSummary += "<tr><td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getCustId();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
           
             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getCustName();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
           
             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getFilm();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
           
             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getShowDate();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
             bookingSummary += "</tr>";
         }
    }
             bookingSummary += "</table>";
             document.write(bookingSummary);
};

Cinema.prototype.getBookings = function() {
  var booking;
  var bookingsTable = "<table border='1'>";
  for ( booking in this.bookings ){
       bookingsTable += "<tr><td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getCustId();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";
    
       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getCustName();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";
    
       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getFilm();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";
    
       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getShowDate();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";
       
       bookingsTable += "</tr>";
    
  }
  
       bookingsTable += "</table>";
  
      return bookingsTable;
};



var odeon = new Cinema();

odeon.addBooking(140, "Arnold Clark", "Step Up", "22 May 2016 19:45");
odeon.addBooking(193, "Janine Booth", "Lover", "31 May 2016 17:30");
odeon.addBooking(440, "Angela Picker", "Spice N Honey", "09 June 2016 15:00");
odeon.addBooking(390, "Cathrine Macintosh", "Avengers", "13 June 2016 20:30");
odeon.addBooking(420, "Smantha Jones", "Hangover 2", "20 May 2016 16:30");

//document.write(odeon.getBookings());

find.onclick = function () {
  odeon.findBooking();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <input type="text" id="inputBox">
  <input type="submit" value="Find Booking" id="find">
  <br>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.write` in your code overwrites all content, you need to instead create an element for results, and update the results element when the find button is clicked. Consider the example below:

```js
var find = document.getElementById('find');
var inputBox = document.getElementById('inputBox');


function CustomerBooking ( custId, custName, film, showDate ) {
  
  this.custId = custId;
  this.custName = custName;
  this.film = film;
  this.showDate = showDate;
}

CustomerBooking.prototype.getCustId = function (){
  return this.custId;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setCustId = function (custId) {
  this.custId = custId;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getCustName = function (){
  return this.custName;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setCustName = function (custName) {
  this.custName = custName;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getFilm = function (){
  return this.film;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setFilm = function (film) {
  this.film = film;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getShowDate = function (){
  return this.showDate;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setShowDate = function (showDate) {
  this.showDate = showDate;
};

function Cinema () {
  this.bookings = [];
}

Cinema.prototype.addBooking = function(custId, custName, film, showDate){
  this.bookings[custId] = new CustomerBooking(custId, custName, film, showDate);
};

Cinema.prototype.findBooking = function () {
  var findID = parseInt(inputBox.value);
    var bookingSummary = "<table  border='1'>";
    for ( var booking in this.bookings ) {
         if ( findID === this.bookings[booking].custId ) {
             bookingSummary += "<tr><td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getCustId();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
           
             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getCustName();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
           
             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getFilm();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
           
             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getShowDate();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
             bookingSummary += "</tr>";
         }
    }
             bookingSummary += "</table>";
             document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = bookingSummary;
};

Cinema.prototype.getBookings = function() {
  var booking;
  var bookingsTable = "<table border='1'>";
  for ( booking in this.bookings ){
       bookingsTable += "<tr><td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getCustId();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";
    
       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getCustName();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";
    
       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getFilm();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";
    
       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getShowDate();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";
       
       bookingsTable += "</tr>";
    
  }
  
       bookingsTable += "</table>";
  
      return bookingsTable;
};



var odeon = new Cinema();

odeon.addBooking(140, "Arnold Clark", "Step Up", "22 May 2016 19:45");
odeon.addBooking(193, "Janine Booth", "Lover", "31 May 2016 17:30");
odeon.addBooking(440, "Angela Picker", "Spice N Honey", "09 June 2016 15:00");
odeon.addBooking(390, "Cathrine Macintosh", "Avengers", "13 June 2016 20:30");
odeon.addBooking(420, "Smantha Jones", "Hangover 2", "20 May 2016 16:30");

//document.write(odeon.getBookings());

find.onclick = function () {
  odeon.findBooking();
};
```

```html
  <input type="text" id="inputBox">
  <input type="submit" value="Find Booking" id="find">
  <br>
  <div id="results"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your approach is that you are using `document.write()` function to write the result of the function. Using `document.write()` once the content of the page is fully loaded deletes all the existing html present on the page and will write the content provided in the `document.write()` function on the page. [W3School Referece](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_write.asp)

Try using a new element for the result instead of the document itself.

```js
var find = document.getElementById('find');
var inputBox = document.getElementById('inputBox');


function CustomerBooking ( custId, custName, film, showDate ) {

  this.custId = custId;
  this.custName = custName;
  this.film = film;
  this.showDate = showDate;
}

CustomerBooking.prototype.getCustId = function (){
  return this.custId;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setCustId = function (custId) {
  this.custId = custId;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getCustName = function (){
  return this.custName;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setCustName = function (custName) {
  this.custName = custName;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getFilm = function (){
  return this.film;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setFilm = function (film) {
  this.film = film;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.getShowDate = function (){
  return this.showDate;
};

CustomerBooking.prototype.setShowDate = function (showDate) {
  this.showDate = showDate;
};

function Cinema () {
  this.bookings = [];
}

Cinema.prototype.addBooking = function(custId, custName, film, showDate){
  this.bookings[custId] = new CustomerBooking(custId, custName, film, showDate);
};

Cinema.prototype.findBooking = function () {
  var findID = parseInt(inputBox.value);
    var bookingSummary = "<table  border='1'>";
    for ( var booking in this.bookings ) {
         if ( findID === this.bookings[booking].custId ) {
             bookingSummary += "<tr><td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getCustId();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";

             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getCustName();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";

             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getFilm();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";

             bookingSummary += "<td>";
             bookingSummary += this.bookings[booking].getShowDate();
             bookingSummary += "</td>";
             bookingSummary += "</tr>";
         }
    }
             bookingSummary += "</table>";
             document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = bookingSummary;
};

Cinema.prototype.getBookings = function() {
  var booking;
  var bookingsTable = "<table border='1'>";
  for ( booking in this.bookings ){
       bookingsTable += "<tr><td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getCustId();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";

       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getCustName();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";

       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getFilm();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";

       bookingsTable += "<td>";
       bookingsTable += this.bookings[booking].getShowDate();
       bookingsTable += "</td>";

       bookingsTable += "</tr>";

  }

       bookingsTable += "</table>";

      return bookingsTable;
};



var odeon = new Cinema();

odeon.addBooking(140, "Arnold Clark", "Step Up", "22 May 2016 19:45");
odeon.addBooking(193, "Janine Booth", "Lover", "31 May 2016 17:30");
odeon.addBooking(440, "Angela Picker", "Spice N Honey", "09 June 2016 15:00");
odeon.addBooking(390, "Cathrine Macintosh", "Avengers", "13 June 2016 20:30");
odeon.addBooking(420, "Smantha Jones", "Hangover 2", "20 May 2016 16:30");

//document.write(odeon.getBookings());

find.onclick = function () {
  odeon.findBooking();
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <input type="text" id="inputBox">
  <input type="submit" value="Find Booking" id="find">
  <br>
  <div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the results table through

```
document.write(bookingSummary);
```

This adds the new HTML for the table directly to the place in the HTML document where this line of code is written. Thus the table is added before the body element.

You can consider adding the html to the body or to a specific element you add to the markup. Let's say you have a div reserved for the resulting table (after the search field).

```
<div id="resultTable"></div>
```

You can then add the table to it

```
document.getElementById('resultTable').appendChild(bookingSummary);
```